# find oblique asymptotes : $f(x) =\sqrt[q]{\frac{a_mx^m+a_{m-1}x^{m-1}+\cdots+a_0}{b_nx^n+b_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+b_0}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

let : $$f(x) =\sqrt[q]{\frac{a_mx^m+a_{m-1}x^{m-1}+\cdots+a_0}{b_nx^n+b_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+b_0}}$$

shuch that : $$m-n=q$$

then : fine oblique asymptotes :

i know that : $y=mx+h$ is oblique asymptotes  such that :

$$m=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}$$

and :

$$h=\lim_{x\to \infty}(f(x)-mx)$$

But I can not answer 
please help .

Comment: Hint: Discard lower order terms and use asympotitcs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the slope, you can do the same calculation you mentioned:

$$\begin{align}
\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x} &= \displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt[q]{\frac{a_mx^m+a_{m-1}x^{m-1} + \cdots+a_0}{b_nx^n+b_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+b_0}}\cdot\frac{1}{x}\\
&= \displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt[q]{\frac{a_mx^m+a_{m-1}x^{m-1}+\cdots+a_0}{b_nx^n+b_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots+b_0}}\cdot\sqrt[q]{\frac{1}{x^q}}\\
&= \displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt[q]{\frac{a_mx^m+a_{m-1}x^{m-1}+\cdots+a_0}{b_nx^m+b_{n-1}x^{m-1} + \cdots+b_0x^q}}\\
&= \sqrt[q]{\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{a_mx^m+a_{m-1}x^{m-1}+\cdots+a_0}{b_nx^m+b_{n-1}x^{m-1} + \cdots+b_0x^q}}\\
&= \sqrt[q]{\frac{a_m}{b_n}}
\end{align}$$

Similarly:

$$h = \displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) - (\text{slope})x = \displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty} \left( \sqrt[q]{\frac{a_mx^m+a_{m-1}x^{m-1} + \cdots+a_0}{b_nx^n+b_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+b_0}} - \sqrt[q]{\frac{a_m}{b_n}}x \right)$$

This limit is trickier. Do you know any methods for evaluating it?

---

Let's try this:

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt[q]{\frac{a_mx^m+a_{m-1}x^{m-1} + \cdots+a_0}{b_nx^n+b_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+b_0}} &= \left(\sqrt[q]{\frac{a_m}{b_n}}\right)x \cdot \sqrt[q]{\frac{x^n + \frac{a_{m-1}}{a_m}x^{n-1} + \cdots + \frac{a_0}{a_m}x^{-q}}{x^n + \frac{b_{n-1}}{b_n}x^{n-1} + \cdots + \frac{b_0}{b_n}}}\\
&= \left(\sqrt[q]{\frac{a_m}{b_n}}\right)x \cdot \left(1 + \left(\frac{a_{m-1}}{a_m} - \frac{b_{n-1}}{b_n}\right)x^{-1} + \cdots\right)^{1/q}
\end{align}$$

where everything in the dots at the end involves powers $x^{-2}$ or smaller. Now, close to $x=1$, we know that $(1+h)^{1/q}$ is well-approximated by $1+\frac{h}{q}$. Thus, we replace the complicated factor on the right with an approximation:

$$\left(\sqrt[q]{\frac{a_m}{b_n}}\right)x \cdot \left(1 + \frac{1}{q}\left(\frac{a_{m-1}}{a_m} - \frac{b_{n-1}}{b_n}\right)x^{-1} + \cdots\right)$$

Multiplying this out, we get that

$$f(x) = \left(\sqrt[q]{\frac{a_m}{b_n}}\right)x + \sqrt[q]{\frac{a_m}{b_n}}\cdot\frac{1}{q}\left(\frac{a_{m-1}}{a_m} - \frac{b_{n-1}}{b_n}\right) + O(x^{-1})$$

Based on this, and encouraged by numeric experiments, I'm pretty sure that we can say

$$h=\sqrt[q]{\frac{a_m}{b_n}}\cdot\frac{1}{q}\left(\frac{a_{m-1}}{a_m} - \frac{b_{n-1}}{b_n}\right).$$

I'd love to see a simpler way to get there. I got this idea from one of the answers to: [How to find the oblique asymptote of root of a function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205587/how-to-find-the-oblique-asymptote-of-root-of-a-function)

Comment: no I can not . what is $h$?

Comment: I'm working on that :/

Comment: From numerical experiments, I can tell that it depends on $a_m, a_{m-1}, b_n$ and $b_{n-1}$, as well as $m$, $n$ and $q$, of course. None of the other coefficients matter.

Comment: Ok, I've edited my answer now, with a value for $h$. It depended on a fancier bit of calculus than I was expecting. Does this problem come from a class assignment? If so, I'm curious what tools you have available to use on it.

Comment: Probably you should use another symbol per the slope, it is already the degree of the numerator

Comment: Good point. I've eliminated the extra use of $m$, although I'm not sure I did it in the most elegant possible way.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs: one way is to rewrite like $\frac{\sqrt[q]{R(x)/x^2}-k}{1/x}$ and next to apply De l'Hopital theorem

Comment: Do you mean $x^q$, rather than $x^2$?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs: oh yeah, you know what I mean

Comment: let $f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{x^3-7}{x-2}}$ So : $y=x+1$ but oblique asymptotes
 $y=x+1$ and $y=-x-1$

Comment: Ok, that's a point. I was so focused on finding $h$, I didn't really think about what happens when $x<0$. If $q$ is even, then $f$ can only take on positive values. Thus, if the oblique asymptote on the right is $sx+h$, then the one on the left will be $-(sx+h)$