# Wrong application of L'Hôpital's rule?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, asymptotics

I was trying to find the right oblique asymptote of the following function:
$$ g(x)= \frac{x^2+(x+2)\cosh(x)}{\sinh(x)}=\frac{x^2}{\sinh(x)}+(x+2)\coth (x)$$
Now since $\frac{x^2}{\sinh(x)}\to 0$ and $\coth(x)\to 1$ as $x\to \infty$, it is easy to see that this asymptote is $y=x+2$. However, when I try to find this asymptote using L'Hôpitals rule, I get a different result: 
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to \infty}g(x) & =\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x^2+(x+2)\cosh(x)}{\sinh(x)} \\
& \stackrel{LH}{=}\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{2x+\cosh(x)+(x+2)\sinh (x)}{\cosh(x)} \\
& =\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{2x}{\cosh(x)}+1+(x+2)\tanh(x) \\
& =\lim_{x\to \infty} x+3
\end{align}$$
since $\frac{2x}{\cosh(x)}\to 0$ and $\tanh(x)\to 1$ as $x\to \infty$. This suggests that the asymptote is $y=x+3$ instead of $y=x+2$.

A quick look at the function using WolframAlpha shows that $y=x+2$ is indeed the correct asymptote, so I highly suspect that I somehow applied L'Hôpitals rule in a wrong way. I have however no clue as to what I did wrong. Could anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Please note that that’s limit is completely meaningless for the calculation of the asymptote and also the way to calculate with de l’Hopital is uncorrect.

Comment: Yeah okay. So I guess the problem with this approach is that it is completely arbitrary in what parts of the limit are evaluated and what parts are left as a linear approximation?

Comment: If $f$ is  $any$   function such that $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\infty$ then $\infty=$ $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=$ $\lim_{x\to\infty}x=$ $=\lim_{x\to \infty}x+1=$ $\lim_{x\to \infty}x+2=$ $\lim_{x\to \infty}x+3.$ But that tells us nothing about asymptotes. We have $\lim_{x\to \infty}g(x)-(x+2)=0,$ which is why the line $y=x+2$ is an asymptote of the curve $y=g(x).$

Comment: Exactly you can’t calculate the limit in this way throwing away  some parts and keeping the others. You have to calculate it properly and as described here below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to be assuming that L'Hôpital preserves asymptotes, when it's not the case.

Take for instance
$$
\frac{x^2(x+2)}{x^2},
$$
with the obvious asymptote $x+2$. If you take derivatives to use L'Hôpital, you get
$$
\frac{3x^2+4x}{2x}=\frac{3x+4}{2},
$$
and the asymptote is not the same.

Comment: The problem here is not that l’Hopital do not preserve the asymptote, the problem is that the limit is completely meaningless to calculate the asymptote.

Comment: @Martin Argerami Ah okay, I missed that. Thanks! Do you also happen to know why asymptotes aren't preserved?

Comment: I cannot give a deep reason. L'Hôpital addresses the fact that $f(x)/g(x)$ and $f'(x)/g'(x)$ have the same limit at infinity if the latter exists, but it doesn't tell you anything about the two quotients behaving the same.

Comment: The wikipedia article on L'Hôpital says something about its geometric interpretation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#Geometric_interpretation). Does this imply that the slope of the asymptote is preserved?

Comment: Wait, of course it doesn't. Your example is proof of that. But then I wonder what this geometric interpretation even is all about?

Comment: @Grimp0w: Read the wikipedia article more carefully. It talks about a **parametric** curve tracing $(f(t),g(t))$, and so if $f'(t):g'(t)$ tends to a constant ratio, then $f(t):g(t)$ also. It says nothing about a curve defined as the graph of a function of one coordinate, in this case tracing $(f(x)/g(x),x)$.

Comment: This answer is completely meaningless in m opinion!

Answer (score 5):

To find the asymptote:

$$y=mx+n$$

you should calculate separately the following limits:

$$m=\frac{g(x)}{x}$$

for the slope, and

$$n=g(x)-mx$$

for the intercept.

Take also a look here:

[How to find the oblique asymptote of root of a function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205587/how-to-find-the-oblique-asymptote-of-root-of-a-function)